# responsive iframe, full width, but set height

Tags: css, iframe, responsive-design, sass

I am trying to make my youtube embedded video 100% width of the screen [like can be seen here](http://bobsinclar.com/) but without black space between the edges which can be seen here at the side of the video. this is caused by me setting a `max-height` of `600px`.

[image] .

I am able to make the video responsive, and I want to set a `max-height` on it so that when the screen is big that it doesn't take up the entire screen, but instead just a section that is responsive but remains the same height like on the site I have shown above.

[Please see jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/a53ft5dq/). If you resize the jsfiddle and make it go as big as it can you will see that it stretches below the end of the screen. I want to prevent this, but without creating black space between the video and the iframe border. By setting `max-width` on the `iframe` this black space appears which i want to avoid.

I hope there is no confusion, but if so please let me know and i can provide more details. I can see that the `iframe` attributes are constantly changing in the page I have provided as an example, but cannot see where this is happening.

```css
#home-video {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  /* 16:9 */
  padding-top: 25px;
}

#home-video iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.main-image {
  width: 100%;
  background: url(http://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/976/cpsprodpb/10E0E/production/_88043196_bret_hart_1920x1080.jpg) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-image">

</div>

<section id="home-video">
  <iframe id="video " src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/QP5_n5UmbHc "></iframe>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page you provided uses this [plugin](https://github.com/pupunzi/jquery.mb.YTPlayer) to achieve that effect.

The plugin allows you to set a video as a kind of a background image in the same way as in the page you provided.

Hope it helps.